# How do I read my new tropical fish thermometer?

Tags: aquarium, fish, equipment

I bought some last minute items for our tank before we started to get any fish, and one of them was a thermometer. We didn't look at it closely until we got home, and then realised we had no idea how to read it. In other words, it's not like a normal thermometer.

If you look at the picture you'll understand what I mean.

Info: I am getting corydras and Betta sorority - tropical fish thriving at around 27 °C - and it is a 'Petworks glass thermometer'.

[image]

Comment: Turn the thermometer or your head so that you face directly in front of your eyes.

Comment: I've got to say, I'm very impressed with how much research you're doing for your betta sorority. Thank you for doing so much work _before_ you get the fish! If you fancy chatting about your fish, we're always in [The Litter Box Chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10964/the-litter-box) if you want!

Answer (score 4):

You don't exactly mention what your difficulty is in reading the thermometer. The scale from bottom to top reads `0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40` (combine the digits left and right of the indicator).

So how does it work? There is this red liquid in a reservoir in the bottom. As this liquid heats up, it expands. When it expands, it can only go upwards, into the scale. How much the liquid expands is an indicator for how warm the liquid is. This is what the thermometer is based on. So if you look at it from right in front, you can see how high the red liquid sits. You can then read off the scale what temperature corresponds with that.

Comment: this type of thermometer do have a narrow angle where you can read it so you need to rotate it slowly until the red column is visible.

Comment: Yep, I wanted to include that, but couldn't find the words for it.

Answer (score 3):

To add to what JAD has already pointed out, these thermometers can be difficult to read. I was in the same position when I started fish keeping. The key to being able to see where the red line appears is to make sure you are looking at the line on the thermometer straight on.

Line yourself up directly in front of the thermometer with your head looking straight forwards and you should be able to see the thin red line. It may take a bit of time before you can read it at a glance but you'll soon get used to it.